# Vercel ssl cerificate for db with prisma

Tags: environment-variables, prisma, vercel

How can I use an SSL certificate for prisma in my vercel project which will be called by env file for my prisma.

I want to use it like this

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@0.0.0.0:3306/database?sslcert=certificate.pem"
```

My prisma looks like:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```